# how can you change remove a class on one li and move it to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

So I am in the middle of coding a navigation bar for the side of my website and I am creating it so that you click on a `li`, inside of it is an `a` tag with no `href` attribute so that it acts like a button (I don't use `#` since it jumps to the top of the page and I don't want that)it has a drop down section come out underneath it pushing the other tabs down. What I've found online is

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

or

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
});
```

(and other variations of this)

However after I tested this out several times, either by adding multiple classes to each `li` or attempting to change the class active to an `id` and I've had no luck.

EDIT: It seems like the code works perfectly in other testing websites (codepen/jsfiddle) but it doesn't seem to work in my own browser when I open up the VisualStudio emulator (opens in the actual browser window)

Here's my code that contains this navigation bar: http://codepen.io/PorototypeX/pen/sjDBL

Comment: IS JQuery loaded? Are you adding that on document ready?

Comment: sibling? shouldn't that be children ?

Comment: No @Joraid other li's are `siblings` to `li`.

Comment: Ouh, i thought you are adding the active class to the <a> not to the <li>. Check my answer.

Comment: @epascarello yes I do have the jquery core on my main code, which I first seem to have found the issues (I made sure there was nothing linking to anything else) and I posted the example on codepen so people can look at just the navbar (I've also seen codepen uses a lot of jquery without the plugin, which is the reason why I left it out, unless I'm just a little crazy.) but either way I still have the same issue

Comment: @epascarello nevermind on my statement. seems like I am a bit crazy haha.

Comment: @Jgoodwyn do you loading jQuery library in the `<head>` section of your document and your custom script just before the `</body>` tag?

Comment: @mdesdev I've put all of my scripting above the `</head>` tag and nothing in the actual body section istelf

Comment: @Jgoodwyn ok, put jQuery library just before `</head>` tag and you custom script like this `<script>$(function() { $('li').click(function() { $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active') }); });</script>` just before `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This might help :

```
   $("ul.navbar > li").click(function () {
        $("li[.active]").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Just cause it's easier for me to comment here, what makes the difference between the class in the brackets [] than just having li.active?

Comment: @Jgoodwyn no difference at all.   li.active and li[.active] is same.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually your code is fine**, but it seems you are using JQuery, and it's not a native part of JS it self, it utilizes JS. **So first you need to load JQuery.**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

Then try this code, it's the same but a different variation of what you have done:

```
    $(".navbar > li").click(function () {
      $(".navbar").children("li").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass('active');;                      
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWhZ9/1/)

Comment: Like @Jgoodwyn mentioned in the question, best way to go about it is `  $('li').click(function() { $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active') });`, short and simple.

Comment: Ok @Joraid +1 for the effort ;)

Comment: @joraid yeah I know I didn't have the jquery core on the codepen example since I've seen a lot of other projects on codepen that involve jquery and didn't have the script that was needed to run it. However I do have it on my full code, I use VisualStudio so I can use the website emulators, and I still have the issue. But I'll see if I was possibly doing something wrong and see how this goes, thanks.

Comment: @joraid my bad. guess I was wrong about the codepen thing. I'll fix that right away for an updated example

Comment: @Jgoodwyn what is the issue you are facing exactly? cuz your question is not clear. (I've had no luck.) you had no luck into doing what? the classes actually change and only the clicked link becomes active.

Comment: @Joraid I honestly can't say anymore. The code works perfectly on both codepen and jsfiddle but when I open the code on my browser through Visual Studio it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: hahaahha no worries. At least it works on the browser. Good luck completing your project/task.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery not added in the page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/arunpjohny/pen/mrlCc)

---

Another problem could be that the code is not in a dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("ul.navbar > li").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EtxR7/)

Comment: I didn't add that to the codepen since I've noticed it still seems to run a lot of jquery without the plugin in the code.as for my complete code I have had that already added and I still have the issue.

Comment: @Jgoodwyn look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EtxR7/1/) and try to reproduce the issue... also make sure your script is in a dom ready handler

Comment: @Jgoodwyn see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EtxR7/2/ - to use dom ready handler... also check browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: @Jgoodwyn it can't run jQuery without jQuery library, Codepen runs JS code like JSFiddle and others but to run jQuery you'll need jQuery library and of course your script wrapped in the document ready function like in example above.

Comment: @ArunPJohny huh. for some reason it works just the way I wanted it too in the example but when I load it here, my separate full code, it doesnt seem to change.

Comment: @mdesdev oh my bad. I'll fix that real quick then. I must be going crazy haha.

Comment: @Jgoodwyn then you need to findout where the problem is... whether these li elements are create dynamically using javascript.. or are they present in the original page source

Comment: @Jgoodwyn You're not going crazy, relax a little, I see you loaded jQuery into Codepen and now it works just fine.

Comment: @mdesdev I was just poking fun at myself. But yeah. I see that it works in both codepen and jsfiddle but it doesn't seem to work when I open up the code in my browser out of VisualStudio. Don't know if that's more of a software issue or just my browsers (or something else possibly)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong with my jquery. Although the code would work perfectly on outside sources such as codepen and jsfiddle, the only way that it will work on a local server is to have this code instead:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul.navbar > li").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

The `$(document).ready(function() { remaining code goes here... })` allows it to run locally.